# What does FRB stand for in StarCraft?

Tags: starcraft-2

Would someone be so kind as to explain what exactly FRB mean in StarCraft? Is it a mod?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it stands for Fewer Resources per Base, as explained [here](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=324001).

> Fewer Resources per Base is the brainchild of Barrin, the Starcraft 2 mapmaker who first started drawing attention to the question, “What effect does the amount of resources available at each base have on Starcraft 2?”